# Create Package in Bower Using bitbucket repository

Tags: bitbucket, bower

I am trying to register a package using `bower register <name> https://git@bitbucket.org..` but bower is not creating a new package and throwing error as it is not a valid url and URl has to start with git://. But in bitbucket they have given Url with https:// and git@bitbucket.org.

I have kept trying with https:// for registering the package but still problem persits. It is not allowing to register the package inside the bower.

So I need some help on creating package in bower with bitbucket repository so i hope someone would have done it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Has this been solved yet? I have the same issue: a bitbucket repo that I want to distribute using bower, but the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try to config  git global and try

```
 git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

 bower register <name>
```